# PHP form not send any $_POST value

Tags: php, mysql

### Question.php

```
    <?php
include 'Pre-function.php'

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Start.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="nav">
    <a href="Homepage.php">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div> 

<div class="question"> 
    <div class="A4">
        <form action="Answer.php" method="POST">
        <?php getQuestion($conn);  ?>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Pre-function.php

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';

function getQuestion($conn) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM question ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($result){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
           $question_id = $row['question_id'];
           $question_body = $row['question_body'];
           $option_a = $row['option_a'];
           $option_b = $row['option_b'];

            echo '

                <h2 class="qtitle">'.$question_body.'</h2>
                <label 
                for='.$question_body.'>Yes</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="'.$option_a.'" value="'.$option_a.'">
                <input type="hidden" name="'.$question_id.'" value="'.$question_id.'">
                <hr>

            ';  
            }

    }

}

?>
```

### Answer.php

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

  if(isset($_POST['answer'])){

      print_r($_POST);
}

}


?>
```

The value checkbox and hidden input did not send any value on the Answer.php page. It did not send any error or warning. **'Option_a' == 'Yes'** value and **'question_id' == S1,S2,S3 and so on**. Each **'question_id'** have their own question and user have to tick if **yes**. So i want send these value on another page. I hope any of you guys can help me.

Comment: unticked checkboxes are not submitted!

Comment: You should define the name of checkbox and hidden field as Array.. Because it have multiple checkbox and hidden fields.

Comment: So i should do question_id[ ] like this ..

Comment: Please show the actual HTML code for the form that this creates as well. No one here has your database available, so we can not properly reproduce the exact output of your PHP code to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand what you actually want to do but not sure what you are actually trying to achieve by saving the options as name and question_id as hidden input.

How i would approach this is saving the question_id as name for the options and i would suggest to use radial buttons if its an yes or no question. Anyways to solve your problem make the following changes to your question format in pre-function.php

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';

function getQuestion($conn) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM question ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($result){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
           $question_id = $row['question_id'];
           $question_body = $row['question_body'];
           $option_a = $row['option_a'];
           $option_b = $row['option_b'];

            echo '

                <h2 class="qtitle">'.$question_body.'</h2>
                <label>'.$question_body.'</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="'.$question_id.'" value="'.$option_a.'">
                <input type="checkbox" name="'.$question_id.'" value="'.$option_b.'">
                <hr>

            ';  
            }
    }
}

?>
```

Now here each question having two options will have the same name corresponding to the question and values as the options. Now your Answer.php should look like

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){    // if submit is true

 // if you want to print all answers then loop through the question id
 // $_POST[$question_id] gives you the value of the answer 
 //i.e the option the user has chosen for that particular question

$query = "SELECT * FROM question ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $question_id = $row['question_id'];
       echo $_POST[$question_id];
    }
}
}
?>
```

Hope this makes sense and helps. :)

check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) for more info on checkboxes.